# Mass assigning Office 365 licenses to users

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm attempting to assign licenses to (over 60) user accounts using powershell rather than the online portal. In the below I have specified admin accounts (all of which are a-firstname.lastname@domain.co.uk) as a test data set. I've been following this technet article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771770.aspx

```
$AdminUnE3 = Get-MsolUser -All -UnlicensedUsersOnly -Searchstring "a-"; $AdminUnE3 | foreach {Set-MsolUserLicense -AddLicenses "reseller-account:SPE_3"}
```

However I am prompted with the following:

```
cmdlet Set-MsolUserLicense at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters
ObjectId:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the objectId or the UPN of the user to which you are assigning the license, something like this:

```
foreach {Set-MsolUserLicense $_.ObjectId -AddLicenses "reseller-account:SPE_3"}
```

the user object might not have an objectid property, you can use UPN also:

```
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName (or something like that) -AddLicenses "xxxxx"
```

Comment: Additional note: Usually, for new accounts, usage location is not defined. That will give you an error indicating so when you apply the license. You will have to Set usage location, then add the license in those case. I.E. Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $User -UsageLocation "US"   (You should put the actual usage location corresponding to the location of the users, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is first to assign -UsageLocation for all the users first then proceed by licensing them; assigning a license without the usage location results to an error.